# ¿Porque mi código php no procesa mi archivo excel?

Tags: php, laravel, linux, excel, ubuntu

Tengo un ecommerce y desde que lo emigre a un servidor de ubuntu me causo varios conflictos entre ellos dejo de cargar archivos excel mediante un formulario lo cual no tenía problemas. No se si se trate de permisos de linux. Dejo el código de la carga.

```
public function uploadImport(Request $request){
        $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'select_file' => 'required'
        ]);

        if($validation->passes()){
            $archivo = $request->file('select_file');
            $excel = $request->file('file');
            $new_name = rand() . '.' . $archivo->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $archivo->move(public_path('temporal'), $new_name);

            $datos = Excel::toArray(new ProductsImport(), public_path('temporal') . '/' . $new_name);

            return response()->json([
                'message'           => 'Proceso terminado correctamente',
                'archivo'           => $new_name,
                'class_name'        => 'alert-success',
                'datos'             => $datos[0]
            ]);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'message'           => $validation->errors()->all(),
            'class_name'        => 'alert-danger'
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Has revisado los logs de PHP? Revísalos

Answer (score 2):

Prueba de esta forma si ocupas guardar el archivo también en el storage usa el las dos líneas de código. pero para importar el archivo de excel no es necesario guardarlo en una carpeta.

```
public function uploadImport(Request $request){
        $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'select_file' => 'required'
        ]);

        if($validation->passes()){

            $archivo = $request->file(); 

            // Únicamente si ocupas guardar el archivo en storage
            $new_name = rand() . '.' . $archivo->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Storage::disk('local')->put('temporal/' . $new_name , $archivo['select_file'] );

            $datos = Excel::import(new ProductsImport(), $archivo['select_file'] );

            return response()->json([
                'message'           => 'Proceso terminado correctamente',
                'class_name'        => 'alert-success',
                'datos'             => $datos
            ]);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'message'           => $validation->errors()->all(),
            'class_name'        => 'alert-danger'
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Gracias pero ya resolví el problema. Tenía que otorgar permisos a la ruta en donde se encontraban los excel.